# Numpy how to create a 1 dimensional array with different datatypes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, row

I want a numpy array with rows in the format ["" 0 0 0]
So with datatypes (U25, int16, int16, int16)

However when I create the array with these different datatypes I get:

```
users = numpy.empty((10000, 4), "U25,int16,int16,int16")
print(users)

[[('', 0, 0, 0) ('', 0, 0, 0) ('', 0, 0, 0) ('', 0, 0, 0)]
 [('', 0, 0, 0) ('', 0, 0, 0) ('', 0, 0, 0) ('', 0, 0, 0)]
 [('', 0, 0, 0) ('', 0, 0, 0) ('', 0, 0, 0) ('', 0, 0, 0)]
 ..., 
 [('', 0, 0, 0) ('', 0, 0, 0) ('', 0, 0, 0) ('', 0, 0, 0)]
 [('', 0, 0, 0) ('', 0, 0, 0) ('', 0, 0, 0) ('', 0, 0, 0)]
 [('', 0, 0, 0) ('', 0, 0, 0) ('', 0, 0, 0) ('', 0, 0, 0)]]
```

However what I want is:

```
[['' 0 0 0]
 ['' 0 0 0]
 ['' 0 0 0]
 ..., 
 ['' 0 0 0]
 ['' 0 0 0]
 ['' 0 0 0]]
```

I believe this is a one dimensional array (correct me if wrong), what am I doing wrong? The users array appears to return a four dimension array, instead I want four values of different datatypes per row.

Comment: Why did you use (10000,4) shape instead of (10000,)?  The `4` is built into the compound `dtype`.  A  1d structured array consists of (n,) records, each record containing several fields, and display with `()`.

Comment: Oh that was silly of me thanks - your advice worked